# printing a multiple figures in a single PDFfile

Tags: loops, printing, figure

there is a folder containing multiple CVS (excel) files. i wrote below, to plot figures of each file (representing a data-set) and then print; but each figure is printed in different PDF file 
how can i modify this m file

```
     directory_name=uigetdir(pwd,'Select data directory');
directory_name=([directory_name '\']);
files=dir([directory_name,'*csv']);

if isempty(files)
   msgbox('No raw files in this directory')
end
if isempty(files)
   msgbox('No raw files in this directory')
end 

for i_files = 1 : length(files);
        filename=files(i_files).name;disp(filename)
    titles(i_files) = {filename};
    cc=hsv(33);
    figure 
    X=[];IND=33;
    X=load([directory_name,filename]);
    plot(X)
    xlabel('time')
    ylabel('angle(degree)')
    legend('repetitive lifting')
    title(filename)
    set(gcf,'Units','inches');
screenposition = get(gcf,'Position');
set(gcf,...
    'PaperPosition',[0 0 screenposition(3:4)],...
'PaperSize',[screenposition(3:4)]);
print -dpdf 
end
```

Comment: "i wrote below"?  What "m file"?

Comment: looking for a code let me printing all figures in one PDF file

Comment: What language did you write this in? vba?

Comment: Can you fix the formatting of your code?  It isn't clear what is in the `for` loop and what isn't.